# remove all empty pages

Tags: formatting

I want to remove all empty pages in my book.

I tried     \documentclass[openany]{book}    , but page numbers changed and new chapters sometimes begins from an even numbered page.

What I want is something like this. (Page 2 is removed in PDF.)

[image: emptypage removed]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `openany` is meant to allow pages to open on an even-numbered ("verso") page.  If you want to "remove" empty pages but not change the pagination which had first counted these empty pages, then you probably want to use an external tool like [PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/). But I don't understand why you'd want to do this, so I suppose you might mean something else....

Comment: So you want to remove (semi) blank pages (they may still have a header/footer) before each chapter but still maintain the regular pagination?

Comment: I wouldn't do this with LaTeX as it may scr*w up your headers, footers, and margin paragraphs. Also LaTeX may not converge with a stable output document because of floats may be migrating and never end up at a stable page. The following [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841856/detect-and-remove-blank-pages-in-pdf-file-with-perl) may be useful.

Answer (score 10):

It seems a slightly strange request but what I think you are asking for is

```
\renewcommand\cleardoublepage{%
 \clearpage
 \ifodd\value{page}\else\stepcounter{page}\fi
}
```

In other words redefine `\cleardoublepage` simply to step the page counter to force the page to be odd rather than throwing a blank page.

Comment: I was trying to implement this idea but I didn't know how to test if odd or even.

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](http://texblog.org/2007/07/09/documentclassbook-report-article-or-letter/) `book` by default is a double-sided document leading to several empty resp. white pages after some chapters because new chapters are starting on odd pages.

You can remove these "trailing" white pages by using the `oneside` option. Make sure that this could change your page layout. The differences between documents using `onside` or `twoside` are explained [here](https://de.sharelatex.com/learn/Single_sided_and_double_sided_documents).

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this – being able to open a chapter on recto/verso isn't the same as not having both recto and verso.